# The following query works in mysql but not on my php page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query, which works in MySQL Workbench, but appears to fail when I run it on my php page. Am I not allowed to use my WHERE AND NOT LIKE clause after the join? I am not sure why this query works in MySQL Workbench but not the php page. As soon as I remove the WHERE AND NOT LIKE the page runs just fine...

```
// Query for cascade
$query = sprintf("SELECT p.id, m.display_name, m.updated_at, group_concat(meta.value) as value, p.path 
                FROM metadata_custom meta
                JOIN page as p on p.id = meta.page_id
                INNER JOIN metadata m on p.metadata_id = m.id
                GROUP BY p.id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT m.id, name, m.updated_at, m.account_id, path FROM cascade_publish.file
                JOIN metadata m on m.id = cascade_publish.file.metadata_id
                WHERE path NOT LIKE '%.jpg' 
                AND path NOT LIKE '%.png' 
                AND path NOT LIKE '%.gif' 
                AND path NOT LIKE '%.js' 
                AND path NOT LIKE '%.dll' 
                AND path NOT LIKE '%.atn'");

$stid = mysql_query($query);

//display success or error depending on query
if(!$stid) {
    echo 'error with sql statements';
}
```

Comment: Can you post the PHP code please

Comment: where is the PHP code where it does not work ?

Comment: Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/metadatafeednew.php on line 88 error with sql statements

Comment: line 88 is the end of the query

Comment: how are you running the query? exactly as it says, sprintf may be complaining cause you're using it, but not defining anything. post the code so we can see

Comment: Error seems obvious, there's not enough variables/values to fill the % in your query. Can you have your PHP code to take a peek at?

Comment: btw, % is used by sprintf. you may just need to escape those percents in the like clauses. \% - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Yeah that looks like the issue...

Comment: ok - as per your update, you really are calling sprintf with no replacement values. sprintf isnt even necessary here. You should switch to mysqli or pdo and use prepared statements. This whole approach looks like it is asking for trouble,

Comment: Updated it to use msqli, works fine now.